# Axios get an undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-hooks

There is a problem
There is a class for working with API

```
export default class RickAndMortyApi {
    api = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api',
    });
    getCharacters() {
        this.api.get('/character/?page=1')
            .then(response => {
                return response.data.results; //array with data. Everything works correctly
            })
    }
}
```

In this class, I am getting a response from the server. Everything works correctly.
But when I want to get this data in a component, I get an *undefined*

Component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
               charactersRequested();
        const data = rickAndMortyApi.getCharacters();
        console.log(data); //undefind
        charactersLoaded(data);
          }, []);
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)